# Predicate for entity with dictionary as property

Tags: core-data, ios7, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have a simple coredata entity which looks likes this.

```
@interface Event : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id eventType;  // this is a dictioary


@end
```

The eventType property is a dictionary that looks like this

```
eventType":{"id":1,"typeDescription":"Sale"}
```

What I've been trying to do is fetch all event objects whose eventType has a **typeDescription keyValue of "Sale"**

Entities with that value defintely exist in my database but I get return zero results.

This is my code for executing the fetch

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }




    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = RKObjectManager.sharedManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
     NSPredicate  *eventTypePredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventType.typeDescription == %@",@"Sale"];

    NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate ;
    compoundPredicate=[[NSCompoundPredicate alloc]initWithType:NSAndPredicateType subpredicates:@[eventTypePredicate]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:eventTypePredicate];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

      NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

     NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: Is eventType defined as a transformable attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can store a Dictionary in Core Data is by archiving it as NSData.

When you click on the attribute type drop down you will see the list of supported types:

[image: Supported Attribute Types]

Notice how Dictionary is not one of them. This is because a dictionary is a very complex object type with a tree length that is undefined at run time. Since Core Data is an object persistence framework it needs to know all about your objects before you try and run queries on them etc.

Thus, the big limitation to storing a Dictionary in Core Data is that you cannot search for any values nested in your dictionary since they have to be persisted as Binary Data.

Since you said you need to find all entities whose typeDescription value is "Sale" you have partly answered your own question. Simply make an attribute "typeDescription" with a type of String. Then you only need search for all entities where typeDescription = Sale